# Isn't a hung jury proof of reasonable doubt?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

I don't understand the logic with allowing additional trials after a hung jury.  Isn't the fact that the prosecution can't get 12 jurors to agree the accused is guilty proof that guilt was not proven beyond a reasonable doubt, and so he should be acquitted?

Why does a not guilty verdict have to be unanimous as well?

Comment: Note that decisions do not have to be unanimous (at least in common law jurisdictions). One or even two dissenters can be permitted depending on jury size and other factors.

Comment: @Nij That may be true in countries like the UK, but verdicts in the US must be unanimous (which was established in Ramos v. Louisiana. In the US, a common saying is that '[i]t only takes one to hang'.

Comment: The jury didn't think there was reasonable doubt.

Comment: As a scientist I fully agree with your assessment. (Un)fortunately this is not how the world works. I wouldn't be surprised though if there could be a decision in the future which will exactly establish this principle

Comment: Not a complete answer, but the argument presented here is trivially invalid because jurors are not necessarily reasonable, so some may decline to convict due to *un*reasonable doubts, that a reasonable jury would have discounted.

Answer (score 33):

#### No. It means the existence of reasonable doubt is in doubt...

One cannot conclude the question of guilt in either direction, so one must try again to see if a different jury can answer the meta-question, to then answer the legal question of guilt.

#### ... or is not being addressed

If only one person is voting against the consensus, or as many as are allowed by the jurisdiction, they are overruled. That's the allowance made for bias that has somehow reached the jury despite the filtering done beforehand.

If more people are voting against the majority so that consensus is not possible, it is potentially because someone has made up their mind on the question of guilt regardless of what (some significant part or the weight of) the evidence indicates, defeating the purpose of the trial and providing all the evidence.

A person not accounting for all the evidence can't be said to have reasonable doubt of guilt, since the doubt may be excluded by the remaining evidence. Similarly, guilt beyond reasonable doubt cannot be supported by only partial evidence, as exculpatory evidence may be among the part not accounted for.

#### ... or cannot be addressed by that jury at all.

Finally, a jury split on the decision of how to weigh the evidence cannot claim either to have or to have dismissed reasonable doubt, because they cannot agree on what a reasonable doubt is, in the first place.

Comment: "If no consensus is possible, it is invariably because someone has made up their mind on the question of guilt regardless of what (some significant part or the weight of) the evidence indicates" - that seems like a very naive view. Even accounting for all evidence, people can disagree.

Comment: That's a fine answer except for the fact that it is only the lack of reasonable doubt that is supposed to be need proven. I would say the real answer is 'history' rather than that the unanimity criteria for acquittal actually makes sense when compared against the statement of the basic rule (that is, that the prosecution bears the entire burden and must prove the case beyond reasonable doubt to the satisfaction of all jurors). A system without hung juries would still match that statement (indeed, would match more closely as there would not be the hung jury exception).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I've removed the firmness of that statement, however it does need to be read in conjunction with the following section. If they disagree so much on what doubts are reasonable, they can't be said to agree there is or is not any.

Comment: Exactly @user2357112.  A minority disagreeing does not mean that person is wrong or didn't consider all the evidence. They may be guided by different experiences.  And they may be right.  Actual truth isn't up to a vote.

Comment: It's extremely weird to suggest the decision of guilt is about truth, when the standard is merely beyond reasonable doubt. In the absence of any other information to the contrary, it must be assumed that all members of the jury are equally capable of applying logic, sense, experience, knowledge, and the facts of the case to reach the decision that most accurately reflects reality.

Comment: If there was reasonable doubt, the result wouldn't be a hung jury, it would be "not guilty (because of reasonable doubt)". A jury may very well be hung because one juror has _unreasonable_ doubts and thinks their doubts are reasonable.

Comment: "potentially because someone has made up their mind on the question of guilt regardless" or politically motivated charges were brought. This is the intended failure mode of politically motivated charges: hung jury after hung jury until the government is fed up.

Comment: @Joshua That allows the process to be the punishment; defense is tied up in courts forever.

Comment: @Ryan_L: I couldn't find a case where more than a couple attempts were made. Generally speaking a politically motivated case will not be retried after the first hung jury.

Comment: @Nij How many jurors are expected to dance on the head of your pin, please? "… the existence of reasonable doubt is in doubt..." still necessarily means there's a reasonable doubt.

Comment: That's the literal opposite of what the statement means. If reasonable doubt is in doubt, it is not possible to say that reasonable doubt exists. For example, because a juror has unreasonable doubt, or the jury as a whole does not agree whether a particular burden of proof has been met.

Comment: @Nij How many iterations would you like? If the doubt of doubt is in doubt… ad infinitum, ad nauseum.

The Question should be what a "hung" jury is. To me, that means  the jury isn't at first unanimous and, even after reconsideration, can't return a 10-2 decision… so basically, is 2/12 a "reasonable doubt"?
In a democracy, what weight should 2/12 carry?

The UK (and all British-based systems I've heard about) say that's so far from a reasonable doubt that even after weeks - sometimes years - a re-trial would be better than an aquitall for doubt.

Comment: I'm not interested in a debate on what should count as what. If you have a different question, ask it in the appropriate way; if you want to write an opinion on how juries decide, please do it elsewhere.